# Making a message reminder like Slack's with Google Chat API and Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hangouts, google-chat

I am making a Google Apps Script that interacts with the Google Chat API, I see that I can make ui changes in Google Sheets with Google Scripts. Is there a way to create the same ui interaction as Slack's message reminder inside Google Chat? Here is the link: https://slack.com/help/articles/208423427-Set-a-reminder

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Google Chat API](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat) to create a [chatbot](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/concepts/bots) which uses the methods [create()](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/create) of the class `spaces.messages` to create messages of the type [Event](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/Event).

In that way you could share in a chat room or a group room event reminders that you can set at a certain time and users can receive them as messages to their chat by the bot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it helped me a lot. But now I'm facing a new issue, the trigger I made to send the reminder message every certain time doesnt work when deployed, it only works when executing the trigger from the text editor. Have you ever faced this issue with ClockTriggerBuilder.